# How does Firebase AppCheck in Flutter handle device integrity checks (e.g., rooted/jailbroken devices)?

Tags: flutter, jailbreak, firebase-app-check, google-play-integrity-api, devicecheck

I have integrated Firebase AppCheck into my Flutter application. The documentation mentions that for iOS, it uses DeviceCheck and/or App Attest, and for Android, it uses Play Integrity. However, in Flutter, there is only one code snippet to obtain the token:

```
final appCheckToken = await FirebaseAppCheck.instance.getToken();
```

But how does Flutter handle the detection of "tampered devices," "rooted," or "jailbroken" devices, as mentioned in the documentation? For example, if a device is rooted, what does this Flutter library do? There are no examples or documentation regarding these functionalities; only the token retrieval function is provided.